# "on_raw_reaction_add" working but "on_raw_reaction_remove" not returning guild?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

***I coded on_eaw_reaction_add and it works just fine***

```
    @commands.Cog.listener() 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):

        msgID = 754487460142121070
        user = payload.user_id
        member = payload.member

        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot1.guilds)
        
        canarinho = get(member.guild.roles, name="canarinho")

        if not payload.guild_id:
            return

        if payload is not None:
            if payload.message_id == msgID:
                if str(payload.emoji) == ":canarinho:":
                    await member.add_roles(canarinho)
```

***But when I try to remove roles it get stuck there, i think im doing something wrong pulling the specific guild***

```
    @commands.Cog.listener() 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 754487460142121070 :

        member = payload.user_id

        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

      #here ->  role = get(member.guild.roles, name='canarinho')

        if not payload.guild_id:
            return

        if payload is not None:
            if payload.message_id == 754487460142121070:
                if str(payload.emoji) == ":canarinho:":
                    print('Working')
```

**ERROR WHEN REMOVING REACTION**

```
    File line 123, in on_raw_reaction_remove
        role = get(member.guild.roles, name='canarinho')
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

**EDIT**
I think there's something to do with `payload.user_id` is a user ID, not a Member object

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: Yes i did enable

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting doesn't mean that anything's wrong with the guild. It says that there's no guild in `NoneType`, which according to your line means member is of `NoneType`.

That makes sense as the payload does have a `member` field, but it is `None` for role removals as per [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent).

Use `payload.user_id` instead and find the user/member from there.

Comment: I change ``payload.member``  for  ``payload.user_id`` and now im getting this error : ``AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'guild'``

Comment: use Client/Bot.get_user https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user

Comment: You should also get used to IDs being numbers and not objects with properties. You'll save yourself a lot of disappointment

Comment: `guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)` and
`member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "✅":
        reaction_role = payload.member.guild.get_role(role_id=968335072916815892)
        await payload.member.add_roles(reaction_role)

async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    if payload.emoji.name == "✅":
        reaction_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Reaction')
        await member.remove_roles(reaction_role)
```

if you are not using discord.ext you should use `client.get_guild` instead of `bot.get_guild`